# RecyclerView scrolls after filling parent container

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with wrap_content, the height works well when the recyclerview has some items, but when RecyclerView fills the parent, the RecyclerView starts to scroll.

this is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activity.RegistroVentaActivity$BusquedaFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlManualSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- some items kind of header -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlResults"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/palette_flat_asphalt_3"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvResultsHint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/palette_flat_asphalt_3"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/search_results_hint"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvProductosCoinsidencias"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvResultsHint"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:columnWidth="@dimen/rv_productos_column_width"
                android:padding="@dimen/rv_item_padding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Note: the layout is a fragment (ViewPager), parent is a
>   CoordinatorLayout.

so the "header" stays always in screen and RecyclerView starts to scroll
i need to scroll everything together when recyclerView reach height parent.

how can i to do it?

im ussing

- com.android.support:design:24.0.0
- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0

i have tried

- nestedScrollEnabled true, false
- hasFixedSize true, false
- autoMeasureEnabled true, false
- LinearLayoutManager
- GridLayoutManger
- CustomsLayoutManater (from searching in google)
- Old official recyclerview versions

nothing seems work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behaviour of RecyclerView. There are two ways you can do to achieve your goal:

1. Make the Header the first item in the List used by the RecyclerView.
2. Use a vertical LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView, where the header is the first child view of the LinearLayout and other items are below the Header.

Comment: i can scroll the content together like i asked, but scrolling does not collapse the CollapsingToolbarLayout, what i need to config in ScrollView in order to Call the Collapse Effect of CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: NestedScrollView (instead of ScrollView) did the work of collapse CollapsingToolbarLayout, thank you very much :D